# Can you set the same static ip address/netmask (no gateway) on multiple interfaces using netsh?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ipv4, netsh

I don't have an environment where I can test this currently. In Windows 7, can you set the same static ip address/netmask (no gateway) on multiple interfaces using netsh from command line? Or will it give me some sort of error? I ask because I need to change two interfaces (flip them essentially) and don't want to disable one in between changing the other.

For example, if I have the following:

Local Area Connection 1:  192.168.1.123 255.255.0.0

Local Area Connection 2:  192.168.1.234 255.255.0.0

And I want to flip them like so

netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection 1" static 192.168.1.234 255.255.0.0

netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection 2" static 192.168.1.123 255.255.0.0

My hope is that it will perform both commands, one after the other, successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this.  You need to use a FOR loop on the command line:

```
FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command
```